# Problem about Instrument amplifier from LM358 at high frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, high-frequency

I am researching about instrument amplifier circuit by use op-amp is LM358.

[image]

In this circuit gain is 1 by Rgain=R2=20k, R1=R3=10k.

Testing is define frequency range 1 Hz-10 kHz but when this circuit is tested on 10 kHz sine wave input, see figure below, vout is not correct same sinewave input.

[image]

In datasheet of LM358 bandwidth maximum at 1 MHz or 100 kHz. I have a question that in my range research LM358 can not working in instrument amplifier?

But when I am testing LM358 to be buffer input sinewave 10 kHz it is working correctly.

Comment: Correct, LM358 is a terrible choice. You are seeing gain and phase errors because it has significant distortion and low slew rate and bandwidth. Note that despite an overall gain of 1, you are using a gain of 2 on the first two amps, which leaves them with less ability to correct errors by feedback.

Comment: I replace CA3140 instead LM358 it is good output .Because it high slew rate and bandwidth than LM358 right ?

Comment: The LM358 is never used for audio because it is noisy, produces crossover distortion and its slew rate is so low it causes problems above only 2kHz at high levels.

Comment: My instrument amplifier is used for measurement voltage drop across load (R,C circuit).

Answer (score 4):

This circuit is working just at "max slew rate".

[image]

If you lower Vgen (V4 and V5) or "fr" a little (2x), it should be "good".

EDIT: Tried also with an LT6203 at 100 kHz. It is ok.

[image]

Comment: I think CA3140 can be fix this problem .How are you thinking ?

Comment: Sorry. Don't have CA3140 in my databank sheets. Will try with a rail-to-rail opamp LT6203. It is ok.

Comment: Thank you so much for testing LT6203 but It can not find in Thailand .

Comment: Ok. Search rail-to-rail opamp. I think it will fit. With TL082c, ok until 200 kHz.